# GDB's commands handling

Tags: gdb, command

im using GDB to debug a C code in eclipse, and i wanted to ask a question about the GDB handling multiple commands. 
if i send the GDB multiple commands through an external software for example:
im sending 'bt', and 'p counter', and than 'help'.

is it possible that the 'bt' command is taking too long to process and return an answer that the GDB will suspend the 'bt' command handling and will try to handle the next command?

it doe'snt make sense to me if it did, but it is important for me to know if it is possible.

i checked in google and i have read the gdb tutorial but never found explanation about the GDB handling commands that are sent to it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check [GDB Internals](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdbint/) which talks about many important GDB operations and algorithms. If you have time it is good to dig deeper by looking at GDB [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/) to understand well.

Comment: do you know if what i asked is possible?